# Keeping connections alive

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, apache, http

Is it possible to keep a client connect (http) to my server alive and return data via that connection when data is available at the server end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is in essence [COMET](http://infrequently.org/2006/03/comet-low-latency-data-for-the-browser/).

Comment: Can this be done with python?  i.e. accept a client connection, keep the connection open, then return server data when data is available back to the client?

Answer (score 1):

I think twisted can handle this kind of thing very well. [external link](http://zenmachine.wordpress.com/2009/09/19/twisted-and-comet-comet-in-60-seconds/)